# Calling fetchall() after performing a stored procedure returns me an empty list

Tags: mysql-connector-python

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `create_merkmal`(IN malter int, IN geschlecht tinyint(1), IN groesse int, IN Tier_tierID int)
BEGIN
   insert into Merkmal(malter ,  geschlecht , groesse, Tier_tierID)
   values (malter ,  geschlecht , groesse, Tier_tierID);
   SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

The ID of `Merkmal` is set to AutoIncrement.
And the stored procedure works fine. It creates a new entry in the database and returns the ID when I am calling it in mysql Workbench like this:

```
CALL create_merkmal(4,1,33,0);
```

But when I am trying to use this procedure in Python with Flask and mysql.connector:

```
...

def callSoredProcReturn(procName, data):
    try:
        myDatabase = mysql.connector.connect(**dbLoginInfo)
        cursor = myDatabase.cursor()
    except mysql.connector.Error as e:
        print('[ERROR WHILE CONNECTING TO DATABASE]: ', e)
    else:
    
        cursor.callproc(procName, data)
        reVal = cursor.fetchall()
       
        myDatabase.commit()
        cursor.close()
        myDatabase.close()
       
        return reVal



@app.route("/profil/create", methods= ['POST'])
def addEntry():
   try:
       
       merkmalID = callSoredProcReturn('create_merkmal', (13,1,444,0))
       print(merkmalID)
        
   except mysql.connector.Error as e:  
        print(e) 
        return abort(400, '[ERROR]: '+str(e))
   
   return Response(status=200)

...
```

It creates a new row in the database but it doesnt return me the ID.
It just printing me an empty list `[]`

[The structure of Table `Merkmal`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38zfX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok my stored procedure looks like this now:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `create_merkmal`(IN malter int, IN geschlecht tinyint(1), IN groesse int, IN Tier_tierID int, OUT re_ID int)
BEGIN
 insert into Merkmal(malter ,  geschlecht , groesse, Tier_tierID)
values (malter ,  geschlecht , groesse, Tier_tierID);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO re_ID;
END
```

and my Code:

```
def callSoredProcReturn(procName, data):
    try:
        myDatabase = mysql.connector.connect(**dbLoginInfo)
        cursor = myDatabase.cursor()
    except mysql.connector.Error as e:
        print('[ERROR WHILE CONNECTING TO DATABASE]: ', e)
    else:
    
        reVal = cursor.callproc(procName, data)
        #reVal = cursor.fetchone()
       
        myDatabase.commit()
        cursor.close()
        myDatabase.close()
       
        return reVal


@app.route("/profil/create", methods= ['POST'])
def addEntry():
   json = request.get_json()
   print(type(json))
   print(json)
   print('----------')
   print( json['profilInfo']['profilName'])
   try:
       
       merkmalID = callSoredProcReturn('create_merkmal', (13,1,666,0,0))
       print(merkmalID)
     
   except mysql.connector.Error as e:  
        print(e) 
        return abort(400, '[ERROR]: '+str(e))
   
   return Response(status=200)
```

The output `(13, 1, 666, 0, 25)`. The last value is the wanted ID.

Its kind of a workaround since I get the whole row back but I can work with it.
If someone has a better solution to my problem, feel free to share :)